# performance of querying DataTable columns using LINQ

Tags: c#, performance, linq, optimization, datatable

What is the speed of running the query below a worst-case 10^8 times? Would it be significantly faster if I only had to run it 100 times and access a local variable with the stored result 10^8 times? If the performance hit of using the former is <10 seconds, that's fine.

```
private static bool CsvContainsColumn(DataTable table, string columnName)
{
    return table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Any(column => column.ColumnName == columnName);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you measure it yourself in that particular scenario?

Comment: The answer would probably depend on the structure of the DataTable.  You'll have to measure it in your context.

Comment: What would be your recommended method for testing its performance?

Comment: Run it in a loop for a total of 10^8 times and time it. You can use the Stopwatch class in the System.Diagnostics namespace. Some people say there are problems with it, but it has worked fine for my needs in the past